# ¿Como se puede condicionar un combobox en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Tkinter y estoy intentando hacer una interfaz gráfica que permita el registro de información. Para registrar la información el usuario tiene que seleccionar una opción y de acuerdo a esa opción se le tienen que mostrar una lista con ciertas opciones dependiendo de la opción que se escoja. He intentado condicionar la selección pero los resultados no se desplegan haciendo la primer selección.

```
if(self.combo.get()!=""):

         if(self.combo.get()=="oh"):
                self.combo2["values"] = ["a","b"]
         else:
                self.combo2["values"] = ["c","d","e"] 


else:
        self.combo2["values"] = [""]
```

Realmente no sé si es recomendable hacer esto ya que soy nueva utilizando Tkinter, así que pido asesoría para poder entender.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente hay dos formas de actualizar de forma dinámica un Combobox.

### Argumento `postcommand`

Permite asignar una callback que será llamada cada vez que el combobox sea desplegado.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  ttk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(
            self, values=["Frameworks gráficos", "Frameworks webs"])
        self.combo2 = ttk.Combobox(self, postcommand=self._combo2_update) 
        self.combo.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.combo2.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def _combo2_update(self):
        now = self.combo2.get()
        if (combo_sel:= self.combo.get()) == "Frameworks gráficos":
            values=("Tkinter", "Kivy", "PySide2",
                    "Toga", "WxPython", "PyGtk", "PyQt5")
        elif combo_sel == "Frameworks webs":
            values=("Django", "Flask", "Pyramid", "Viper",
                    "Bottle", "Sanic", "CherryPy", "Web2py")
        else:
            values = ()

        if now not in values:
            self.combo2.set("")
            self.combo2.config(values=values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Evento `<<ComboboxSelected>>`

Se lanza cada vez que se selecciona un item en un combobox. En éste caso lo enlazaríamos al primer combobox, para que cuando se seleccione en él se modifique el segundo. La ventaja es que podemos limpiar la selección del segundo sin que el usuario interactúe con él:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  ttk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(
            self, values=["Frameworks gráficos", "Frameworks webs"])
        self.combo2 = ttk.Combobox(self) 
        self.combo.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.combo2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self._combo2_update)

    def _combo2_update(self, event):
        now = self.combo2.get()
        if (combo_sel:= self.combo.get()) == "Frameworks gráficos":
            values=("Tkinter", "Kivy", "PySide2",
                    "Toga", "WxPython", "PyGtk", "PyQt5")
        elif combo_sel == "Frameworks webs":
            values=("Django", "Flask", "Pyramid", "Viper",
                    "Bottle", "Sanic", "CherryPy", "Web2py")
        else:
            values = ()

        if now not in values:
            self.combo2.set("")
            self.combo2.config(values=values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]